# Inserting a string method into an string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to make a selection for a set of values, each of the methods return a string array which I am trying to put into a string array in the main. Here is the code:

```
string[] array = { MethodA1(), MethodA2(), MethodA3() };
```

I am trying to make the string[] array, just one item. This works: (but it only allows the user to show/select one value)

```
string[] array = MethodA1();
```

Can anyone think of a way to allow multiple method returns into an array?

Comment: Try searching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012380/merge-2-arrays-using-linq, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177080/how-to-merge-several-arrays-in-a-list-using-linq

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

```
string[] array = MethodA1().Concat(MethodA2()).Concat(MethodA3()).ToArray();
```

**Edit**:  It sounds from your comments that you are actually trying to achieve something entirely different: to select the results of one of these methods based on a parameter.  Do you mean something like this?

```
private string[] SelectFiles(object userInput)
{
    string[] array;

    if (userInput == 1)
    {
        array = MethodA1();
    }
    else if (userInput == 2)
    {
        array = MethodA2();
    }
    else
    {
        array = MethodA3();
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is it possible to select a specific method instead of displaying all of them? :)

Comment: Isn't that just `string array = MethodA1()` per your question?  I think you might need to give some concrete examples of what you're trying to achieve, because I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: sorry, the items in the string array are files, once placed in the string[] array, those are then send to another method which sorts them into ascending or descending order based on the users choice. I have tried an if statement like 'if(userInput == 1) { string[] array = {MethodA1();} ' but I cannot return the array out of an IF statement. I hope that helps?

Comment: I think you should edit your question to include this & some context (e..g more code!).  You asked how to combine the results from multiple methods but it sounds like you actually want to choose which method to execute depending on some other parameter.  None of this is expressed clearly in the question.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `SelectMany` to flatten everything to a single `string[]`:

```
string[] array = (new[] { MethodA1(), MethodA2(), MethodA3() })
    .SelectMany(a => a)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider

```
List<string>
```

You could simply use

```
myList.AddRange(stringArrayMethod());
```